# Use unique features of a component while it's registered on a common interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, serilog, microsoft.extensions.logging

Let me give an example using [Serilog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog) and [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line). The application uses Serilog as its logging component, the loggers can be used as `ILogger<T>` by dependency injection. Serilog has a nice feature called message template that allows something like:

```
//_logger is an instance of ILogger<SomeClass> injected in the constructor

var position = new { Latitude = 25, Longitude = 134 };
var elapsedMs = 34;

_logger.LogInformation("Processed {@Position} in {Elapsed} ms", position, elapsedMs);
```

It's working fine. My question is: the purpose of using `ILogger<T>` is to decouple my code from Serilog so that I can switch to other logging components easily (though no one will do this because Serilog rocks!!!), using Serilog unique feature "message template" contradicts the original intention. So what's the best practice here? This is not only a question for logging, but also for other components.

Comment: Does Serilog implement an interface that extends `ILogger<T>` and includes those extra members? I'm guessing it does and that you just inject using that interface instead.

Comment: I would say that the answer here is to follow the Dependency Inversion Principle which gives us in defining application-specific abstractions—such as an application-specific logger interface. You should define the interface as such that you can build both an MS Logging *and* Serilog adapter on top of this that suits your needs. By creating both adapters (instead of solely creating a Serilog adapter) you can verify whether your logger abstraction functions with multiple implementations.

Comment: @jmcilhinney No extra members here. Serilog uses the same signature as `ILogger<T>`, it just enhanced the input strings, allowing objects in the string. Other loggers don't support this feature.